# At most one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups which are abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian simple group.

Prove that $G$ has at most one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups which are abelian, and at least one conjugacy class of maximal subgroups which are non-abelian.

I don't really understand what the question means. Does it mean:

If $H$ is an abelian maximal subgroup, then there is at most one (distinct) $gHg^{-1}$?

If $H$ is a non-abelian maximal subgroup, then there are at least one (distinct) $gHg^{-1}$? (This is obvious right?)

Also, I am not sure how to prove it, but I have a lot of partial results below. Thanks.

---

My attempt:

I have proved all the previous parts of the question. The partial results are:

1) I have shown $$\left|\bigcup_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}\right|\leq 1+(|H|-1)[G:N_G(H)]$$, with equality if and only if all the distinct $gHg^{-1}$ intersect trivially.

2) If $H$ is a proper subgroup, then $G\neq \bigcup_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.

3) If $G$ has two distinct maximal subgroups $A$ and $B$ which are abelian, then $A\cap B=\{1\}$.

I also know if $H$ is a maximal abelian subgroup, then so is $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: No it doesn't mean what you said. It means that any two maximal subgroups that are abelian must be conjugate, and there exists at least one maximal subgroup that is not abelian.

Comment: As a hint, note that any two maximal subgroups of a nonabelian simple group that are abelian must have trivial intersection. (I find the question a bit strange because in fact a finite nonabelian simple group cannot have any subgroups that are maximal and abelian.)

Comment: @DerekHolt (+1) Thanks. Any other hints? I know the above result already from my partial results.

Comment: A subgroup that is disjoint from its conjugates is a Frobenius complement. By counting elements you can show that there is at most one conjugacy class of these. (But a Frobenius group cannot be simple, so this situation cannot really arise.)

Comment: Thanks! I managed to prove that there is only one conjugacy class of abelian groups, using counting elements as you hinted.

How about for existence of maximal non-abelian subgroup? If $pq\neq qp$, I was thinking how about the group $\langle p,q\rangle$, but it may be the whole group.

Comment: Any noncyclic finite group has at least two conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups.